# Converting a RGBA image to RGB image

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to convert a RGBA image to a RGB image (8-bit unsigned integer per channel). At first I used OpenCV and the following function for that

```
m_bufferMat.data = (uchar*) (ptr1);
m_bufferMat.convertTo(m_bufferMat, CV_8UC3);
```

But for the other parts of the application I don't need to use OpenCV, so I tried to convert the image myself so I don't need to link and include the OpenCV library. The fastest method I could imagine is to iterate trough the buffer and copy just the first 3 bytes to another buffer like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    ptr1++;
}
```

But for that I need to copy which could be not realy fast. The OpenCV function is 1.5 times faster than my own function. Has anybody an idea why? Can I implement a function where I don't need to copy?

Comment: I assume you are using `-O3`.  You could use SIMD intrinsics.  You could modify the buffer in place.  Depending on what your code is trying to do, you could change what is done on input or done on output.

Comment: Have you taken a look at OpenCV's implementation of the function?

Comment: OpenCV is strongly optimized, it's often unlikely to reach its performance. But luckily it is open source, so you can have a look at what kind of tricks they use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many optimizations that could be done. Here is a test bench program to try them and a few example optimizations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <functional>

volatile int width = 1920;
volatile int height = 1080;

unsigned char* src = new unsigned char[width * height * 4];
unsigned char* dst = new unsigned char[width * height * 3];
unsigned char* refDst = new unsigned char[width * height * 3];


void DefaultFunc() {
  auto ptr1 = src;
  auto ptr2 = dst;
  for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    ptr1++;
  }
}

void NPreCalculatedFunc() {
  auto ptr1 = src;
  auto ptr2 = dst;
  auto n = width * height;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    *(ptr2++) = *(ptr1++);
    ptr1++;
  }
}

void ReadFullPixelFunc() {
  unsigned int* ptr1 = (unsigned int*)src;
  auto ptr2 = dst;
  auto n = width * height;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    auto srcPix = *(ptr1++);
    *(ptr2++) = srcPix & 0xff;
    *(ptr2++) = (srcPix >> 8) & 0xff;
    *(ptr2++) = (srcPix >> 16) & 0xff;
  }
}
  

void ReadAndWriteFullPixelFunc() {
  unsigned int* ptr1 = (unsigned int*)src;
  unsigned int* ptr2 = (unsigned int*)dst;
  auto n = width * height / 4; 
  unsigned int writeBuf = 0;
  for (int i = n; i; i--) {   
    // by reading 4 pixels, we get to store 3 unsigned ints
    auto srcPix = *(ptr1++);    
    writeBuf = srcPix & 0x00ffffff;
    srcPix = *(ptr1++);
    writeBuf |= srcPix << 24;
    *(ptr2++) = writeBuf;
    
    writeBuf = (srcPix >> 8) & 0xffff;
    srcPix = *(ptr1++);
    writeBuf |= (srcPix << 16);
    *(ptr2++) = writeBuf;

    writeBuf = (srcPix >> 16) & 0xff;
    srcPix = *(ptr1++);
    writeBuf |= (srcPix << 8);
    *(ptr2++) = writeBuf;
  }
  // todo: if width * height is not divisible by 4, process the last max 3 pixels here with the unoptimized loop
}

void ReadAndWriteFullPixelXmmFunc() {
  unsigned int* ptr1 = (unsigned int*)src;
  unsigned int* ptr2 = (unsigned int*)dst;
  auto n = width * height / 4;
  unsigned int writeBuf = 0;   
  __m128i reorder = _mm_set_epi8(0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 14, 13, 12, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0);
  for (int i = n; i; i--) {        
    auto srcPix4_ro = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)ptr1), reorder);    // read 4 source pixels, remove alpha bytes, pack to low 12 bytes of srcPix4
    ptr1 += 4;
    _mm_storel_epi64((__m128i*)ptr2, srcPix4_ro); // store 2 first pixels
    ptr2 += 2;
    auto shifted = _mm_bsrli_si128(srcPix4_ro, 8);
    _mm_storeu_si32(ptr2, shifted); // store 3rd pixel
    ptr2 += 1;    
  }
  // todo: if width * height is not divisible by 4, process the last max 3 pixels here with the unoptimized loop
}



unsigned long long PrintShortestTime(std::function<void()> f, const char *label, unsigned long long refTime) {
  unsigned long long minTicks = ~0ull;
  memset(dst, 0, width * height * 3);
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    auto start = __rdtsc();
    f();
    auto end = __rdtsc();
    auto duration = end - start;
    if (duration < minTicks) {
      minTicks = duration;
    }
  }
  if (memcmp(refDst, dst, width * height * 3)) { // test that we got the right answer
    printf("Fail - result does not equal refrence!\n");
  }
  printf("%s : %llu clock cycles - %0.3lf x base implementation time\n", label, minTicks, refTime ? ((double)minTicks/(double)refTime):1.0);
  return minTicks;
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i++) {
    src[i] = rand() & 0xff;
  }
  DefaultFunc();
  memcpy(refDst, dst, width * height * 3);

  auto refTime = PrintShortestTime(DefaultFunc, "default, unoptimized", 0);  
  PrintShortestTime(NPreCalculatedFunc, "n precalculated", refTime);
  PrintShortestTime(ReadFullPixelFunc, "n precalculated, reading 1 pixel at a time", refTime);    
  PrintShortestTime(ReadAndWriteFullPixelFunc, "reading and writing ints at a time", refTime);
  PrintShortestTime(ReadAndWriteFullPixelXmmFunc, "with xmm intrinsincs", refTime);
}
```

For me, on visual studio & x64 or x86, the last version takes about 0.4x as long time as the basic version:

```
default, unoptimized : 7511848 clock cycles - 1.000 x base implementation time
n precalculated : 7383696 clock cycles - 0.983 x base implementation time
n precalculated, reading 1 pixel at a time : 7354644 clock cycles - 0.979 x base implementation time
reading and writing ints at a time : 4613816 clock cycles - 0.614 x base implementation time
with xmm intrinsincs : 3036824 clock cycles - 0.404 x base implementation time
```

It would probably be possible to optimize further by unrolling the loop, writing memory in larger chunks.